# WPF Not sending MouseMove events after CaptureMouse();

Tags: wpf, canvas, mousemove

I'm trying to have a WPF canvas with rounded rectangles on that I can drag round using the mouse.  However once I try and capture the mouse on the canvas I don't get the move events any more.

This is a "mycanvas" user control and the rectangles are "foo" user controls.  The XAML for these (minus the preamble) are:

mycanvas.xaml:

```
<Canvas MouseDown="CanvasMouseDown" MouseMove="CanvasMouseMove" MouseUp="CanvasMouseUp" Background="White">

    <my:Foo HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="97" Canvas.Top="30" x:Name="m_foo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="128" />
</Canvas>
```

foo.xaml:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="15" Background="Plum">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Foo" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And then the handlers are:
mycanvas.xaml.cs:

```
private void CanvasMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is Foo)
    {
        m_moving = e.Source as Foo;
        CaptureMouse();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_moving != null)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(m_moving, e.GetPosition(this).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(m_moving, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
    }
}

private void CanvasMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
    m_moving = null;
}
```

The MouseDown fires and so the CaptureMouse gets called (and works because I can no longer close the app or click anything else in it!) but the MouseMove never gets called anymore - so where do the MouseMove events get sent now???

If I alt-tab to another application and then go back now suddendly the MouseMove is called and the Foo moves with the mouse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try either:

```
Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
```

or

```
m_moving.CaptureMouse();
...
if (m_moving != null)
{
    m_moving.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    m_moving = null;
}
```

The mouse events were being raised by the Foo, not by the Canvas, so when you capture the mouse with the Canvas you prevent them from being raised.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. (Still don't quite understand why but hey..)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the MouseMove event on the Window:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseMove += MouseEventHandler;

    }

    private void MouseEventHandler(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point position = e.GetPosition(this);

        Canvas.SetLeft(ElipseElement, position.X-5);
        Canvas.SetTop(ElipseElement, position.Y-5);    


    }
}
```