# Set UI Element Position to Mouse Position

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote a little Program that should display a Ellipse at the exact mouse position. The Problem is that, the way Iam doing it right now , The Mouse and Ellipse Position are only exact at the center of the Screen. If I put the mouse further away to the windowborder they drift further and further away.

I use the MouseOver Element to Update the Mouse Position.

[image]

Here is my code:

```cs
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Main_Grid.Children.Clear();

   MousePos_Ellipse = new Ellipse();
   Point MousePos_Point = new Point();

   MousePos_Point = Mouse.GetPosition(Main_Grid);

   Main_Grid.Children.Remove(MousePos_Ellipse);

   SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();


   mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(55, 255, 255, 0);
   MousePos_Ellipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
   MousePos_Ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
   MousePos_Ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

   // Set the width and height of the Ellipse.
   MousePos_Ellipse.Width = 15;
   MousePos_Ellipse.Height = 15;
   // At this Point I do my Positioning
   MousePos_Ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(left: MousePos_Point.X - ( Main_Grid.ActualWidth / 2)  , top: MousePos_Point.Y - ( Main_Grid.ActualHeight / 2 ), right: 0 , bottom: 0);

    // Add the Ellipse to the Grid
    Main_Grid.Children.Add(MousePos_Ellipse);
}
```

Comment: use a canvas instead of a grid

Comment: The canvas control is the control you want to use to explicitly position child elements. You will get issues in other controls that implement specific layout styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use a [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of a grid.

With a canvas you can simply set the ellipse position like that:

```
   Canvas.SetLeft(MousePos_Ellipse, MousePos_Point.X);
   Canvas.SetTop(MousePos_Ellipse, MousePos_Point.Y);
```

The Grid control will do automatic positioning and sizing of child elements and is therefore not so suitable for your goal.

Comment: You where absolutly right I edited it and It works just fine. The "Error" with the not fireing event can be fixed when you set a background to the Canvas.    http://stackoverflow.com/a/7766111/5276170

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer; while the answers above will fix your issue, the actual question is not properly resolved. The problem you are facing derives from your interpretation of the issue compared to how the computer sees it.

The position of your cursor relative to the grid is not the same as the position relative to your screen (i.e. different resolutions return different values). This is why our x and y values will be further off the further you get off center. You could fix this by defining that you want your X and Y position **relative to the form**, f.ex, like so:

```
    var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

The noticable difference here is that here, we Point to the client, and therefore get the Cursor's relative position within the form.