# MouseMove Observable on a ReactiveUserControl not getting all events

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to add an Observable to MouseMove events in a ReactiveUserControl using the following code at the constructor:

```
this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
{
    var movingEvents = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(h => MouseMove += h, h => MouseMove -= h);
    var mousePosition = movingEvents.Select(evt => evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this));
    mousePosition.Subscribe(pos => Console.WriteLine(pos.ToString()));
}
```

It works, but sometimes it simply stops "catching" the events for a random period. If I use the same code inside the MainWindow constructor, which is just a Window control, it appears to get all the events.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: We have a helper nuget package that has generated all those events for you. ReactiveUI.events.wpf. Then it becomes like this.Events().MouseMove to get the event

Comment: Also this would likely be just a regular WPF problem I suspect rather than a observable one. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764421/onmousemove-does-not-fire-on-canvas-in-wpf helps

Comment: thanks, @GlennWatson that's much better. I'm still new to rxui and wpf in general and I think the real problem is just that I didn't know that the UserControl won't fire the MouseMove event if it's background isn't set. Doing so fixed the problem!

Comment: I'll change that to a answer then for others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first consider using the ReactiveUI.Events.WPF NuGet package. It contains all the common UI events so you don't have to generate them yourself using FromEventPattern.

For the UserControl issue it's likely to be that you need the background set. WPF by default won't fire them off. See [OnMouseMove does not fire on canvas in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764421/onmousemove-does-not-fire-on-canvas-in-wpf) for more details.